# Code enhancing to avoid CPU time exceeded issue

Tags: apex, bulk-api, cpulimit

How to avoid CPU limit exceeded if the requirement
Is to have a map of field names and values of contacts when the trigger fires? 
Any ideas of how to enhance the code below please :

```
    Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fieldsMap = Schema.SobjectType.Contact.fields.getMap(); //Fields API names

    For(Contact c: trigger.new){
    For(String contactField : fieldsMap){
    If(String.isNotBlank(String.valueOf(c.get(contactField))) ){
        //Add here map of field name (contactField) and its value(c.get(contactField))
}
```

Comment: That's kind of an unusual thing to do. The object essentially already is a map from it's field names to values.

Comment: Is there any reason that it has to be a `map<String,String>`?

Comment: What about `JSON.serialize(c)` `JSON.deserializeUntyped(c)` then? It will get you a `map<String,Object>` that you could add other values to. The code would be simpler at least, but it might not save much execution time. If this code is in a trigger, you could just add the fields on the Contact object and then not give anyone the field level permissions to use them. Those fields would effectively just be for use by the trigger then.

Comment: Hi Martin, 
I want to have a map with field names and values, and add more field names of contact, so tried to use the object but didn't work as can't add more fields , as the list does not support put method:
        
            List<Contact> testContacts = trigger.new;
            for(Contact c: testContacts){
                testContacts.put('firstname', c.firstname);
                testContacts.put('lastname', c.lastname); 
                testContacts.put('description', c.description);            
                testContacts.put('newemail', c.email);
            }

Comment: That's a good idea, but need a formula feed to store the old email and old other fields

Comment: I didn't quite get that last bit; what's a formula feed?

Comment: I meant a field to store the old values of a field

Comment: If you go to JSON and back to a map, it will keep all of the old values there, but again, no guarantees on what that will do to the processing time. It might just be easiest to add the fields to the object.

Comment: I can't help but ask if you've profiled your code to see what part is taking up your execution time? You've obviously omitted other code and it could very well be that it's the other parts that are consuming your time, so would recommend you post more. Also, are there other triggers firing or recursion happening that could also be part of your issue?? Let's look at the total issue.

Comment: I'm testing if the trigger has been fired once , so it is not an issue of recursive triggers, I think the issue is because of having for loop  inside another for loop. I added some fields and created process builders to fill them, but they are missing in the trigger.new for some reason

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to serialize the map and add fields to the map 
Thanks Martin for your help